# Find intersection between a point and a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck on trying to find the intersection between a point and a plane.

$p:\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$ is the coordinates of the point.

$\prod :x + z = 0$ is the equation of the plane.

I have found the normal of the plane $\prod$: $n:\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Which then creates the line that goes through the point: $l: \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\\ 2 \end{pmatrix} +t \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

then I do the following procedure: $1+t+1+2+t = 0$ solving this gives: $t=-2$

I put $t=-2$ into the equation of the line which gives me the following: $x = -1, y = 1, z = 0$ and it's completely wrong.

Could someone help me out please?

Comment: Where did the highlighted $1$ come from in $1 + t + \color{red}{1} + 2 + t = 0$? It looks like you’re substituting the parametric equations into $x+y+z=0$, instead of $x+z=0$.

Comment: It still doesn't make any sence if I ignore the highlighted 1. The equation would then give the following $t=-2/3$

Comment: I get $-3/2$. Maybe that will make more sense.

Comment: Yes indeed. Thank you.

Comment: You don’t mean intersection. Do you mean the point on the plane closest to the original point?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A point on the line is given by $x=1+t,y=1,z=2+t$. (These are the parametric equations of the line.) The condition for that point to also lie on the plane $x+z=0$ is $1+t +2+t=0.$ Thus $t=-3/2.$ Substitution of this value of $t$ into the parametric equations of the line gives the point of intersection or, to use old=fashioned language, the point  at which the line pierces the plane $\mathit{viz.}$$(-1/2,1,1/2).$

Comment: You made me realize I did wrong on $3+2t=0$ which equals $t=-3/2$. 
I also learned that you simply ignore the y coordinate in such case since it simply is 0, doesn't exist. Thank you!